# “Geometric” vs Homotopical completion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, completion

There are two notions of completions of slightly different nature, and I am wondering if there is a precise statement relating them.

The first one is the “homotopical” (or maybe it should be called algebraic) completion of a morphism in a sense of, e.g. the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1556) of Kathryn Hess (section 4), i.e. totalization of a monadic bar-construction.

The second one is the “geometric completion” of a morphism of schemes in the sense of Gaitsgory—Rozenblyum, see for instance [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1738) section 6. Here the completion is calculated using the fiber product $X^{\wedge}_Y= X\times_{X_{\textrm{dR}}} Y_{\textrm{dR}}.$

Is there a way to relate the two in the case when the morphism of derived schemes is representable? More precisely, I am looking for a statement of the type: functions on the geometric completion is the homotopical completion of the morphism of underlying rings. I would also really appreciate a reference if there exists one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to relate the two. First, it's helpful to think of both in terms of universal properties. Since geometric completion is a fiber product, it's a pullback. Meanwhile, the homotopical completion can be defined as a (homotopy) pushout. As Hess remarks, Bousfield's $p$-completion is a special case, and that's a [special case of Bousfield localization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bousfield+localization+of+spectra), and hence can be computed by a particular homotopy pushout. Completion in algebra is also a special case of this machinery. Applying $Hom$ converts homotopy pullbacks to homotopy pushouts and vice versa.

Both of your settings are treated together, in a series of papers by Barthel, Heard, and Valenzuela. [One](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00895) has "derived completion" in the title. On page 4 they have a table relating the algebraic geometry side (geometric completion) with the commutative algebra side (algebraic completion). They introduce what they call a [local duality framework](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03526.pdf) that lets them treat completion (and localization, torsion, etc.) in both settings simultaneously. They then use recollements to relate torsion and completion, and they relate derived completion of rings to certain algebraic stacks. Moreover, they relate comodules over Hopf algebroids (on the algebra side) to quasi-coherent sheaves over algebraic stacks (on the algebraic geometry side).

This work builds on earlier work of Dwyer-Greenlees and Greenlees-May. Some of that is [summarized at the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/091N) (but, I've not read through that treatment fully), and that might save you from the machinery of local duality frameworks.

Comment: Wonderful, an unexplained downvote. What a nice way to start a Sunday morning. Thanks, random unfriendly user!

Comment: Welcome to the club :-) The recent question I asked that Peter Scholze thought was really good got four downvotes and someone complaining about something I wrote as being false, that in all likelihood is probably actually true. Also, downvoting without comments is a long-standing MO tradition, no? /s

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, the downvotes on yours were unjustified (but, 34 upvotes). And yes on the tradition but it seems much worse lately. In 2024 so far, I've had more downvotes than in 2015-2019 combined (and that's omitting the whole Breakthroughs nonsense). I'll bet data would show you that MO has become a more unfriendly, down-voty place. SEDE suggests the average number of daily downvotes in 2024 is bigger than any other year.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWhite, once again your answer is extremely interesting!

Comment: @DavidWhite I wonder why that is...

Answer (score 4):

In the affine case, this is more-or-less proved in [Bhargav Bhatt, [Completions and derived de Rham cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6193)]. More precisely, Kathryn Hess' completion is more akin to Carlsson's *Adams completion*, and the relative de Rham stack is closely related to the derived de Rham cohomology (in some sense, the former is represented by the later). Then the precise statement is Proposition 4.16 *loc. cit.*

PS: In fact, some variant of this also holds for general morphisms, not necessarily closed immersions. It is Theorem 4.10 *loc. cit.*, whose proof depends on the statement for closed immersions.

Comment: Hi Zhouhang! Great to see you here. Last week I happened to mention your work on derived crystalline cohomology at the Midwest Topology Seminar, due to its use of Smith ideals (I was presenting my work with Donald Yau on the subject). Good job!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I’ve read Bhatt’s paper, but I was unable to infer any statements about the de Rham stack from there. I’ll definitely take a second look at the statements you referenced, thank you again!

Comment: @GrishaTaroyan I am not sure about references for relating the de Rham stack and the (Hodge-completed) derived de Rham cohomology, but a prismatic analogue can be found in \[Bhatt–Lurie, [The prismatization of $p$-adic formal schemes](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.06124) §7.3\] or \[Holeman, [Derived $\delta$-rings and relative prismatic cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17447) Lem 3.3.14\].